# What's the difference between `CLK_EN` and `CLK_INTLEN` in the Control1 register of the EMMC module on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: sd-card

In the manual for the BCM2835, the `CONTROL1` register of the Arasan EMMC module has a:

- `CLK_EN` field for "SD clock enable"
- `CLK_INTLEN` field for "Clock enable for internal EMMC clocks for power saving"

What is the "Internal EMMC clock for power saving"?

What is the difference between the "SD clock" and the "Internal EMMC clock for power saving"?

Unfortunately, I'm struggling to distinguish between the two from reading the manual.

Below is the relevant part of the manual I'm referencing:

[image]